# Convert Image to Base64String in SELECT query

Tags: sql-server, image, base64

I have a table `my_table` like this

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
    ([row_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [img1] [image] NOT NULL)
```

I want to retrieve `description` and `img1` as Base64String for a given `row_id`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
    @row_id int
AS
    SELECT
        description,
        img1 -- Need to change this line
    FROM
        my_table
    WHERE
        row_id = @row_id
```

Searching online I found

```
SELECT CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@bin"))','VARCHAR(MAX)')
```

which uses a variable `@bin`. How can I use this code in my select query and replace `@bin` with `img1`?

**UPDATE**

Here is what I'm doing for now

```
DECLARE @img1 varbinary(max)

SELECT @img1 = img1 FROM my_table WHERE row_id = @row_id

SELECT
    description,
    CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@img1"))','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS img1
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    row_id = @row_id
```

which is working but two parts are needed and I'm querying the same table twice. And as you might imagine this is a sample but I've got multiple columns I need to convert to base64.

Comment: `SELECT CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("img1"))','VARCHAR(MAX)')` ?

Comment: @gotqn Thanks but I got `XQuery [value()]: The SQL type 'image' is not supported with sql:column() and sql:variable().`

Comment: Do you really need to do this *in the server*? Is there really nothing *consuming* this result set capable of performing this conversion? (If you do need it in the server, a CLR function would probably work best, where you can just call `Convert.ToBase64String(...)`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I do need it server side indeed. Client side can't cope with `byte[]` for some reason. Never used CLR before, could you explain it further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one might be a little bit better.

```
select 
    description,
    base64_img1 = CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("img1"))','VARCHAR(MAX)')
from (
    select 
        description, 
        img1 = cast(img1 as varbinary(max))
    from my_table
    ) T
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON functions to achieve base64 conversion, assuming your SQL Server version and database compatibility level are recent enough to support it:

```
select * from openjson((
    select description, img1
    from my_table
    where row_id = @row_id
    for json auto
)) with(description varchar(50), img1 varchar(max))
```